# How to merge two datasets with conditions?

Tags: r

Say, I have two datasets:

First - Revenue Dataset

```
Year   Month  Sales Company
1988    5      100    A
1999    2      50     B
```

Second - Stock Price Data Set

```
Date       Company    Stock
19880530     A         200
19880531     A         201
19990225     B         500
19990229     B         506
```

I need to merge these two datasets into one in such a way that the stock price on the month end date (from second data set) should be combined to corresponding month in the revenue dataset (in second data set)

So the output would be:

```
Year   Month  Sales Company  Stock
1988    5      100    A       201
1999    2      50     B       506
```

You can ignore the problem with leap year

Comment: is the second year on the first dataset supposed to be 1999?

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the month and date from the `Date` column and for each `Company` and each `Month` select the row with max `date`. Then join this data to `revenue` data and `select` required columns.

```
library(dplyr)

stock %>%
  mutate(date = as.integer(substring(Date, 7)), 
         Month = as.integer(substring(Date, 5, 6))) %>%
  group_by(Company, Month) %>%
  slice(which.max(date)) %>%
  inner_join(revenue, by = c('Company', 'Month')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(Year,Month ,Sales,Company,Stock)

#  Year Month Sales Company Stock
#  <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <int>
#1  1988     5   100 A         201
#2  2000     2    50 B         506
```

Comment: Where did you get revenue from? Please not: Sales is in a different data frame.

Comment: I considered the name of first dataframe to be `revenue` dataframe and second one to be `stock` ? So I think instead of `revenue` you have to use `sales` ?

Answer (score 0):

First notice that here is no 1999-02-29!

To get the month ends, use `ISOdate` on first of following month and subtract one day. Then just `merge` them.

```
merge(transform(fi, Date=as.Date(ISOdate(fi$Year, fi$Month + 1, 1)) - 1), 
      transform(se, Date=as.Date(as.character(Date), format="%Y%m%d")))[-2]
#   Company Year Month Sales Stock
# 1       A 1988     5   100   201
# 2       B 1999     2    50   506
```

---

*Data:*

```
fi <- read.table(header=T, text="Year   Month  Sales Company
1988    5      100    A
1999    2      50     B")
se <- read.table(header=T, text="Date       Company    Stock
19880530     A         200
19880531     A         201
19990225     B         500
19990228     B         506")  ## note: date corrected!
```